# Bootstrap 4 - Container fill the whole screen, footer shown after scroll

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I have a react app where I use MDBootstrap which is basically Bootstrap4 as my css framework. I have a simple page with login form. I want the page to fill the whole screen no matter what screen size + I want a footer at the bottom to be shown only after a user scrolls down the whole screen. How to achieve that ? How to make container fill the whole available screen + next container to be shown after the previous one is scrolled. I want to achieve something like that
[image]

My code

```
render() {
        return (
            <MDBContainer id={'main'} fluid>'
                <Router history={history}>
                    <MDBRow>
                        <MDBCol>
                            <Header/>
                        </MDBCol>
                    </MDBRow>
                    <MDBRow className={'mt-3'}>
                        <MDBCol>
                            <MDBContainer fluid={true}>
                                <div>
                                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
                                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                                    <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage}/>
                                </div>
                            </MDBContainer>
                        </MDBCol>
                    </MDBRow>
                </Router>
                <MDBRow>
                    <MDBCol>
                        <Footer/>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
            </MDBContainer>
        );
    }
```

Comment: For the first container mark the `min-height:100vh` which will take whole screen and then put your next container.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Post your CSS also.

Comment: I use only bootstrap stuff doesn't have any own css

Comment: Wrap your `Router` with `<MDBRow style={{minHeight:'100vh'}}>  <Router> </MDBRow>`

Answer (score 1):

create another custom css file then define a wrapper class for the login box like this:

```
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      }
   body{
      min-height: 100vh;
      }
```